# Routing/NAT Linux how to (RHEL 7)

Tags: linux, routing, iptables, nat

I have a device (called TANGO) with an IP address of 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0 connected directly using GbE Link to a RHEL 7 server (called LIBRA), where I assigned a static IP on LIBRA GbE port eno3 as 192.168.1.3 netmask 255.255.255.0 so LIBRA and TANGO can communicate.

Now, on the same RHEL 7 server above (LIBRA) I have another port (bond0) with an IP address of 10.8.1.2/24 and DEFAULT GW 10.8.1.1 so my server LIBRA can talk with my main network 10.8.1.0

Now my question, if I have a linux server (called MARIA) on the main network (10.8.1.0) with IP address on ens136 of 10.8.1.3/24 where (MARIA) can reach the RHEL 7 server (LIBRA) via my default GW 10.8.1.1, can now the linux server (MARIA) reach to my device as well (TANGO) with IP address 192.168.1.2/24?

I am trying to figure out how TANGO and MARIA can ping each other and communicate via all ports using my RHEL 7 server LIBRA?

NOTE: my device TANGO is not running OS (it is a camera)

[image: example picture]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved using IPtables service.